# Trouble finding selector to use for first span in a div

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I target styling to the 1st `<span>` (**Foo**) without affecting the 2nd `<span>` (**Bar**) preferably without using a class? IE6 support is not needed. I tried using `first-child` but that only works without the image being there.

I could live with the degradation if I use `.adcodeblock span:nth-child(3)`, but I thought I would check with more experienced people first.

```
<div class="adcodeblock">
  <img src="/images/aUHFgK.jpg" alt="" border="0">
  <span>Foo</span>
  <span>Bar</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the `:first-of-type` pseudo-class:

```
.adcodeblock span:first-of-type
```

See [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=first-of-type) for a browser support table. For older browsers I would use something like this:

```
.adcodeblock br + span
```

Answer (score 10):

If you can live without IE8 and below, you could try

```
.adcodeblock span:nth-of-type(1)
```